# Text is not rendered from base line of image. OK for CHM but not HTML

Tags: html, css, helpndoc

Now this one is confusing me. I decided to try and use the option to align the image to the base line. So in HelpNDoc:

[image: Align to base line]

Now, inside the HelpNDoc editor the actual topic content is rendered like this:

[image: Rendered]

That is as I expect it. And, if I resize my editor:

[image: Rendered when resized]

It still looks great. So, I compile my CHM module and have a look at the same topic in there. here it is with a smaller view:

[image: CHM]

Again, it is all looking great. So now I build the HTML version of the help and upload to the browser for testing. I have tried Firefox, IE, Edge and Chrome. They look like this:

[image: HTML]

See how the text is not starting at the base line of the image? The page in question is here:

http://help.trucklesoft.co.uk/BriefOverview.html

I have looked with the Google Developer Console:

[image: Google Developer Console]

Nothing is immediately jumping out at me. So I went a stage further as I noticed the text is in a span and wondered if it had to do with that:

[image: Span]

Again, nothing is jumping out at me. What is causing the `span` text to not render from the baseline of the image?

Comment: lots of screens but no code here :) ... text and image next to each other ? reset image to vertical-align-bottom and remove float if it is set for img. (idem for a span and a reset to display:inline-block might help too)

Comment: @G-Cyr Ah, OK. I find it odd that I have stated that the image be base aling but it has not fed through into the underlaying CSS style files. The value `middle` was what I was originally using. I have added custom CSS to modify it and it looks good.